# Convert Bundle to Integer (Intents)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

I am attempting to pass an int through an intent to another class and have managed to successfully pass through the integer however I am unsure as how to convert a Bundle to an Integer.

Code from Intent:

```
private void nextPage()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Timer.class).putExtra("totalTime", totalTime);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Code in Timer class:

```
    Bundle time = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(time == null)
    {
        timeDisp.setText("Failed.");
    }
    else
    {
        totalTimeMs = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(time));
        timeDisp.setText(totalTimeMs);
    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intent can hold directly all java primitives types and parcelable/serializable objects.

You may have a confusion that it can also hold Bundles.

Do you really need to put your integer in a Bundle? It can be true for multiple values that logically coupled.

Check [Intent API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your `totalTime` is of type `int` which you pass through `putExtra()` the you can use:

```
int time = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("totalTime");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding your intent to a Bundle, so on the recieving activity you are trying to get data out of an empty Bundle.

You would Add the data to a bundle by:

```
private void nextPage()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Timer.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle():
    b.putString("totalTime", totaltime);

    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then you would retrieve the String from the bundle:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

String time = extras.getString("totalTime");
```

Comment: actually new intent(...).putExtra("tag", value) is valid and adds the data in to the intents bundle